# ion-cards scrolls slowly in iPhone

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-scroll

I have made a page with ion-cards showing the list of items, But the issue is that when I scroll the list fastly it works perfectly on android device(i.e smooth experience) but the issue comes in iPhone devices, it scrolls very slowly in all iPhone devices(i.e lags while scrolling). Please give your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used WkWebViewEngine instead of UIWebViewEngine and that fixed my scrolling issue but a new issue has occurred. Go through [WkWebView does not allow PUT method in iOS devices using ionic3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934125/wkwebview-does-not-allow-put-method-in-ios-devices-using-ionic3)